# push_back() binary tree into vector

Tags: c++11, vector, binary-tree, inorder

I'm trying to put all the elements from a binary search tree into a vector, in order. Here is the function:

edit: adding instructions for clarity.
Write a class for implementing a simple binary search tree capable of storing numbers. The class should have member functions:

```
void insert(double x)
bool search(double x)
void inorder(vector <double> & v)
```

The insert function should not use recursion directly or indirectly by calling a recursive function. The search function should work by calling a private recursive member function

```
bool search(double x, <double> & v )
```

The inorder function is passed an initially empty vector v; if fills v with the inorder list of numbers stored in the binary search tree. Demonstrate the operation of the class using a suitable driver program.

EDIT: Added full code for clarity.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BinaryTree {

private:
struct TreeNode {

    double value;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(double value1,
        TreeNode *left1 = nullptr,
        TreeNode *right1 = nullptr) {

        value = value1;
        left = left1;
        right = right1;
    }
};

TreeNode *root;    //pointer to the root of the tree
bool search(double x, TreeNode *t) {

    while (t) {
        std::cout << "running through t." << std::endl;
        if (t->value == x) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (x < t->value) {
            std::cout << "wasn't found, moving left." << std::endl;
            search(x, t->left);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "wasn't found, moving right." << std::endl;
            search(x, t->right);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "wasn't found." << std::endl;
    return false;
}


public:

std::vector<TreeNode> v;

BinaryTree() {
    root = nullptr;
}

void insert(double x) {
    TreeNode *tree = root;

    if (!tree) {
        std::cout << "Creating tree." << x << std::endl;
        root = new TreeNode(x);
        return;
    }

    while (tree) {

        std::cout << "Adding next value." << std::endl;
        if (tree->value == x) return;

        if (x < tree->value) {
            tree = tree->left;
            tree->value = x;
        }
        else {
            tree = tree->right;
            tree->value = x;
        }
    }

}
bool search(double x) {

    return search(x, root);
}

void inOrder(std::vector <double> & v) {

    {
        if (left)
            left->inOrder(v);
        v.push_back(value);
        if (right)
            right->inOrder(v);
    }
}
TreeNode* left = nullptr;
TreeNode* right = nullptr;
double value;
};

int main() {

    BinaryTree t;

    std::cout << "Inserting the numbers 5, 8, 3, 12, and 9." << std::endl;
    t.insert(5);
    t.insert(8);
    t.insert(3);
    t.insert(12);
    t.insert(9);

    std::cout << "Looking for 12 in tree." << std::endl;
    if (t.search(12)) {
        std::cout << "12 was found." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Here are the numbers in order." << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I'm unable to get the values to push into the vector. Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally do this recursively:

```
#include <vector>    

class TreeNode {
    void inOrder(std::vector<double>& v) const
    {
        if (left)
            left->inOrder(v);
        v.push_back(value);
        if (right)
            right->inOrder(v);
    }

    TreeNode* left = nullptr;
    TreeNode* right = nullptr;
    double value;
};
```

**Edit:** added #include <vector>

**Edit2:** That is how I would do it. Feel free to ask any questions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BinaryTree {
private:
    struct TreeNode {

        double value;
        TreeNode *left = nullptr;
        TreeNode *right = nullptr;

        TreeNode(double value1)
            : value(value1)
        {}

        void inOrder(std::vector <double> & v) {
            if (left)
                left->inOrder(v);
            v.push_back(value);
            if (right)
                right->inOrder(v);
        }
    };

    TreeNode *root = nullptr;    //pointer to the root of the tree

    bool search(double x, TreeNode *t) {
        while (t) {
            std::cout << "running through t." << std::endl;
            if (t->value == x) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (x < t->value) {
                std::cout << "wasn't found, moving left." << std::endl;
                return search(x, t->left);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "wasn't found, moving right." << std::endl;
                return search(x, t->right);
            }
        }
        std::cout << "wasn't found." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
public:


    BinaryTree() {}

    void insert(double x) {
        TreeNode *tree = root;

        if (!tree) {
            std::cout << "Creating tree." << x << std::endl;
            root = new TreeNode(x);
            return;
        }

        while (tree) {
            std::cout << "Adding next value." << std::endl;
            if (tree->value == x) return;

            if (x < tree->value) {
                if (!tree->left)
                {
                    tree->left = new TreeNode(x);
                    return;
                }
                tree = tree->left;
            }
            else {
                if (!tree->right)
                {
                    tree->right = new TreeNode(x);
                    return;
                }
                tree = tree->right;
            }
        }
    }
    bool search(double x) {
        return search(x, root);
    }
    void inOrder(std::vector<double>& v)
    {
        root->inOrder(v);
    }
};



int main() {

    BinaryTree t;

    std::cout << "Inserting the numbers 5, 8, 3, 12, and 9." << std::endl;
    t.insert(5);
    t.insert(8);
    t.insert(3);
    t.insert(12);
    t.insert(9);

    std::cout << "Looking for 12 in tree." << std::endl;
    if (t.search(12)) {
        std::cout << "12 was found." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Here are the numbers in order." << std::endl;
    std::vector<double> v;

    t.inOrder(v);
    std::cout << "values in order:";
    for (double val : v)
    {
        std::cout << " " << val;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I originally tried it recusively, but couldn't figure out how with the instructions wanting me to only have one parameter argument. I've edited the post for clarity on instructions.

Comment: As C++ is case sensitive, please check if you have all occurrences of 'inOrder' written with an upper case O.

Comment: I did, I've added the full code. I had to turn the assignment in without the inOrder() function, but would still like to know what I did wrong.

Comment: So why does it work as a private member, but not a public one?

Comment: There are two functions named inOrder. One in TreeNode (BinaryTree::TreeNode::inOrder) which is private an the other in BinaryTree (BinaryTree::inOrder) which is public. The latter is called in the test code.

Comment: Sorry, the one in TreeNode isn't private. It is defined as a struct and therefore by default public. (As far as I know this is the only difference between struct and class)

Comment: Ok, so we put the inOrder into the struct to have access to pointer and be able to dereference the pointers with the the function. The stand alone function inOrder is just used to access the one because a struct is basically it's own class? Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, but the members in the struct are all public. Also note that the struct TreeNode itself is in the private section of the class Binary Tree and therefore cannot be used outside BinaryTree.